# Android Ksoap2 xml request generaion

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap2

I need to know how to create  soap request in Android its hierarchy for the xml request given below,facing problem creating the SOAP request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://siebel.com/CustomUI" xmlns:upb="http://www.siebel.com/xml/UPBGAttachmentQueryIO">
      <soapenv:Header>
    <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">vadmin</UsernameToken>
    <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">vadmin</PasswordText>
    <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cus:UpsertAttachment_Input>
         <cus:Process_spcInstance_spcId></cus:Process_spcInstance_spcId>

         <cus:Siebel_spcOperation_spcObject_spcId>?</cus:Siebel_spcOperation_spcObject_spcId>
         <upb:ListOfUPBGAttachmentQueryIO>
            <upb:Upbgsrupdateattachmentbc>
               <upb:Id>0</upb:Id>    
               <upb:ActivityComments>Test2</upb:ActivityComments>  
               <upb:ActivityFileExt>jpg</upb:ActivityFileExt>
                  <upb:ActivityFileName>SeeTest3</upb:ActivityFileName>
                  <upb:SrNum>17110700001</upb:SrNum> 
                  <upb:ActivityFileBuffer >ecnoded64bit string </upb:ActivityFileBuffer>

            </upb:Upbgsrupdateattachmentbc>
         </upb:ListOfUPBGAttachmentQueryIO>

      </cus:UpsertAttachment_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Quick response would be appreciated.Thanks